# Serialization of child class from function of parent

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization

I have a number of objects that i want to serialize and read to object's instance later. But, if i try to write a Save function like this:

```
[serializable]
public class ClassA
{
  public int a;
  public string b;
  ...
  public String Save()
  {
  return XmlSerialized.Serialize(this);
  }
}

[serializable]
Class ClassB: ClassA
{
   ****
  bool C;
}
```

The following code returns only objects of class A:

```
ClassA objA = new ClassB();
string s = objA.Save();
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ClassA objA = new ClassB();` wouldn't work. .NET will see the result type is `ClassA` and it knows that `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`. Thus it will just create an instance of `ClassA`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you need to make `bool C` public in order to serialize it.
Next, initiate a new `XmlSerializer` with the type of `this`, and use it to serialize:

```
    public string Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

        using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
           serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
           return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it like you first did:

```
ClassA objA = new ClassB();
string s = objA.Save();
```

Comment: No. Of course, all in my code public. But in Save function XMLSerializer view this as ClassA and store only data of ClassA

Comment: `this` object is actually an instance of `ClassB`, `this.GetType()` will return `ClassB`, so you'll get the data of both classes.

Answer (score 0):

You call the Save method of classA which is why `this` is an instance of class A. By using

```
ClassB objB = new ClassB(); 
string s = objB.Save();
```

you should get the desired result.

(Though i am not quite sure if you need an overload of Save() in ClassB.)

Comment: Thanks. That is a solution that i'll use, but it make my code not structured and hard:(